# Perform line sorting SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is this possible? For example, I want to get the latest date for the value of `PC2Date,Re2Date,Rp2Date` then the resut will be the value of `PC2` or `Re2` or `Rp2`.
I want to add another `column` for the `Result` of the sorting.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id  |  Pc2  |         Pc2Date         | Re2   | Re2Date                |Rp2   | Rp2Date               |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|aaa | PCRej | 2016-12-28 07:44:08.000 | LARej |2016-11-18 20:24:14.000 |RpRej |2016-11-19 19:14:06.000|  
|bbb | PCRej | 2016-11-09 20:57:15.000 | NULL  |NULL                    |RpGd  |2016-11-12 12:23:51.000|
|ccc | PCRej | 2016-10-06 20:07:04.000 | NULL  |NULL                    |NULL  |NULL                   |
|ddd | PCRej | 2016-10-27 14:15:32.000 | NULL  |NULL                    |RpRej |2016-11-02 14:59:30.000|
|eee | PCRej | 2016-10-24 19:30:22.000 | LARej |2016-11-03 09:27:12.000 |NULL  |NULL                   |
|fff | PCRej | 2016-10-24 19:30:22.000 | LAGd  |2017-01-03 08:27:16.000 |NULL  |NULL                   |
```

So for that sample `Condition` the result will be something like this:
**Output**

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id  |  Pc2  |         Pc2Date         | Re2   | Re2Date                |Rp2   | Rp2Date               | Result|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|aaa | PCRej | 2016-12-28 07:44:08.000 | LARej |2016-11-18 20:24:14.000 |RpRej |2016-11-19 19:14:06.000| PCRej |
|bbb | PCRej | 2016-11-09 20:57:15.000 | NULL  |NULL                    |RpGd  |2016-11-12 12:23:51.000| RpRgd |
|ccc | PCRej | 2016-10-06 20:07:04.000 | NULL  |NULL                    |NULL  |NULL                   | PCRej |
|ddd | PCRej | 2016-10-27 14:15:32.000 | NULL  |NULL                    |RpRej |2016-11-02 14:59:30.000| RPRej |
|eee | PCRej | 2016-10-24 19:30:22.000 | LARej |2016-11-03 09:27:12.000 |NULL  |NULL                   | LARej |
|fff | PCRej | 2016-10-24 19:30:22.000 | LAGd  |2017-01-03 08:27:16.000 |NULL  |NULL                   | LAgd  |
```

TIA!

Comment: In your example, result is not a date. In the first row, how do you come up with `PCRej` by using the three date fields as an input?

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably something like this?

```
SELECT t.*, ca.Val AS Result
FROM <<table>> t
   CROSS APPLY (
       SELECT TOP (1) Val
       FROM (
           SELECT CONVERT (NVARCHAR(MAX), t.Re2) AS Val
                  , CONVERT (DATETIME, t.Re2Date) AS ORD
           UNION ALL
           SELECT CONVERT (NVARCHAR(MAX), t.Rp2) AS Val
                  , CONVERT (DATETIME, t.Rp2Date) AS ORD
           UNION ALL
           SELECT CONVERT (NVARCHAR(MAX), t.PC2) AS Val
                  , CONVERT (DATETIME, t.PC2Date) AS ORD
       )
       ORDER BY ORD
   ) ca
```

Comment: Ill try this! thanks ! keep you updated if this works!

Comment: Nice! That's a better answer then mine. +1/

Comment: Order by ORD DESC , as max date is requierd

Comment: Using VALUES instead of SELECT .. UNION ALL is an option to consider.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a case expression to figure out the latest date:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Result = CASE WHEN ISNULL(Pc2Date, '1900-01-01') > ISNULL(Re2Date, '1900-01-01') AND 
                       ISNULL(Pc2Date, '1900-01-01') > ISNULL(Rp2Date, '1900-01-01') THEN 
             Re2
                  WHEN ISNULL(Re2Date, '1900-01-01') > ISNULL(Pc2Date, '1900-01-01') AND 
                       ISNULL(Re2Date, '1900-01-01') > ISNULL(Rp2Date, '1900-01-01') THEN 
             Re2
                  WHEN ISNULL(Rp2Date, '1900-01-01') > ISNULL(Pc2Date, '1900-01-01') AND 
                       ISNULL(Rp2Date, '1900-01-01') > ISNULL(Re2Date, '1900-01-01') THEN 
             Rp2
             END
```

Comment: Ill try this first sir. Thanks! Will keep you updated if this meets my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

you also can refer the following script:

```
    CREATE TABLE #t(id VARCHAR(100),Pc2 VARCHAR(100),Pc2Date DATETIME,Re2 VARCHAR(100),Re2Date DATETIME,Rp2 VARCHAR(100),Rp2Date DATETIME,[Result] VARCHAR(100))
    INSERT INTO #t(id,Pc2,Pc2Date,Re2,Re2Date,Rp2,Rp2Date)
    SELECT 'aaa','PCRej','2016-12-28 07:44:08.000','LARej','2016-11-18 20:24:14.000','RpRej','2016-11-19 19:14:06.000' UNION
    SELECT 'bbb','PCRej','2016-11-09 20:57:15.000',NULL ,NULL,'RpGd ','2016-11-12 12:23:51.000' UNION
    SELECT 'ccc','PCRej','2016-10-06 20:07:04.000',NULL ,NULL,NULL,NULL UNION             
    SELECT 'ddd','PCRej','2016-10-27 14:15:32.000',NULL,NULL,'RpRej','2016-11-02 14:59:30.000' UNION
    SELECT 'eee','PCRej','2016-10-24 19:30:22.000','LARej','2016-11-03 09:27:12.000',NULL,NULL UNION
    SELECT 'fff','PCRej','2016-10-24 19:30:22.000','LAGd','2017-01-03 08:27:16.000',NULL,NULL

    UPDATE #t SET Result=(SELECT TOP 1 c.title FROM (VALUES(Pc2,Pc2Date),(Re2,Re2Date),(Rp2,Rp2Date)) c(title,[date]) ORDER BY c.date desc)
```

```
id  Pc2 Pc2Date Re2 Re2Date Rp2 Rp2Date Result
aaa PCRej   2016-12-28 07:44:08.000 LARej   2016-11-18 20:24:14.000 RpRej   2016-11-19 19:14:06.000 PCRej
bbb PCRej   2016-11-09 20:57:15.000 NULL    NULL    RpGd    2016-11-12 12:23:51.000 RpGd 
ccc PCRej   2016-10-06 20:07:04.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    PCRej
ddd PCRej   2016-10-27 14:15:32.000 NULL    NULL    RpRej   2016-11-02 14:59:30.000 RpRej
eee PCRej   2016-10-24 19:30:22.000 LARej   2016-11-03 09:27:12.000 NULL    NULL    LARej
fff PCRej   2016-10-24 19:30:22.000 LAGd    2017-01-03 08:27:16.000 NULL    NULL    LAGd
```